# How to programmatically set gridcount in Amcharts 4

Tags: amcharts

I have a xychart with labels on the y axis. Every second label is being hidden:

[image]

Google suggests that I can set:

```
valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
```

and:

```
valueAxis.gridCount
```

to the number of grids required by the data.

...but it doesn't have any effect, autoGridCount seems to be missing in the V4 documentation and there is no mention of it being removed.

***How can I programmatically set gridcount?***

EDIT: JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dm6ps08a/)

Comment: can you share the complete config of your chart or create a code pen please?

Comment: @SamuelP. Yes, I've added a JSFiddle to show an example of the behaviour. Note 2029 has no label.

Comment: and what exactly is your problem now? do you want to show all lables?

Comment: Yeh, it looks like I can do that with categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1. But I would like to also have a minimum height for each of the bars so I can show the bullet number.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out you can use `axis.renderer.minGridDistance` to show all labels:

```
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 0;
```

To adjust the row height you can use `series.columns.template.height` to adjust the height of each element. I would suggest to set it to `100%` and set a small border to the items:

```
series.columns.template.stroke = am4core.color('#fff');
series.columns.template.strokeWidth = 1;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
series.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(100);
```

To adjust the row height I would recommend increasing the chart height in general, because amcharts is trying to display all data in the area you provide. So increasing the height of the chart will cause all rows to have equal height and fill the provided area.

If you have varying data and don't know the number of rows, you can set the height of the chart dynamically according to the length of your data array and use an html scrollbar:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('chart').style.height = `${chart.data.length * 50}px`;
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#chartdiv {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPxxqR) I created a code pen to show my suggestion.